# WPF How to rebind image control in ListView to new source?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, controls

I have a listview which I'm using to show and edit records which have a byte array bound to an image control in the listview data template. I want the user to be able to select a different image to change and save the image associated with the record, so I have a button which opens a file picker dialog. Once the file has been picked, I save it to the db and I want the image control to update to the new image.

I have been trying to do this by saving the image on the button click event and then trying to find the image control from code via the visual tree, and then setting it's source from there. Without luck. I've been using the Visual Tree helper to return a list of controls in the item container, which works ok, but it won't add the image control to the list because when it comes to the image control,

```
if (_child is control)
```

returns false. VS also tells me that it cannot convert a System.Windows.Controls.Control to a System.Windows.Controls.Image. It will do it for a textbox.

Is there a better way to update the image source?

Comment: You are doing something wrong if you are using the visual tree helper for anything other than debugging.

Comment: OK I'm new to WPF so how best to find an image control from selected item and change it's source from code behind?

Comment: You should not be using code-behind. Read a few tutorials on WPF such as http://www.wpftutorial.net/.

Comment: I've updated the question for more info

Answer (score 0):

It is merely a `FrameworkElement` as can be seen in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) or assembly metadata, this is because it is not an interactive element. It is in the same namespace because having too many namespaces becomes a pain i suppose.